# Parse json from web service in php

Tags: php, json, parsing

I am trying to parse the following json that I got through a web service in php.

```
$string = [{xxx:"xxx",yyy:"yyy",zzz:"zzz"}, {xxx:"xxx",yyy:"yyy",zzz:"zzz"}];
```

I try to parse it as with json_decode but it doesn't work.

```
$json = json_decode($string);
```

Returns nothing. What should I do?

Comment: Have you turned error reporting on in PHP? Have you tried `print_r($json)`?

Comment: What you show above is not valid JSON, the `$string = ` breaks it. Is it part of your response?

Comment: That's not JSON. It's a Javascript expression. Try the search, this came up before.

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid JSON. First of all, the entire thing needs to be a string. Use single-quotes here. Then, every name/value within the string needs to be double-quoted. Like so:

```
<?php
$string = '{ "one": {"xxx": "xxx", "yyy": "yyy", "zzz": "zzz"}, "two": {"xxx": "xxx", "yyy": "yyy", "zzz": "zzz"}}';
$json = json_decode($string);

var_dump($json);
?>
```

http://codepad.org/sOeEfOnr
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php